# During migration D6->D7 I get an error message "Integrity constraint violation"

Tags: migrations

I use Migrate and Migrate_D2D in my process of migrating from D6 into D7 and I get this message for each an every node when using "MigrateFileUri":

```
    SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'public://instrument/instrumentbilder/63379742-s_1.jpg' for key 'uri': INSERT INTO {file_managed} (uid, filename, uri … and so on…
```

The strange thing is that on another computer with the same development environment (WAMP) most of the nodes are imported without problem with exactly the same code. Something must be different though… Some mysql setting in WAMP maybe?

I have searched for the "duplicate files" in the table "file_managed" and I can confirm that these files are not present in that table. So the duplication must happen during the import. For some reason the node must be saved twice?

I should mention that when importing all files in a separate migration and using MigrateFileFid as file class, there is no problem. The thing is that I need to use urlencode to clean file names and also I want to decide where different files from different node types are to be saved (different destination_dir for different file types), and as far as I understand those options are not available with MigrateFilFid.

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicates that your underlying database is having a problem. It looks like you've tried the migration multiple times, and that parts of it were successful previously. What the error message is stating is that you are attempting to insert duplicate records into the database, or at least duplicate keys for an existing record. You need to reset/empty the NEW database prior to running migrate and migrate_d2d to remove the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes thats true, I have tried the migration several times and then rolled it back to adjust the code… I have checked the table in question, and the files that 'migrate' complains about are not present there. I am not sure what you mean by resetting the database. If I do that I will lose every setting ever made?

Comment: You do lose every setting. Migrate allows you to choose which types to migrate, have you tried just doing selective migrations? If you are using MySQL or MariaDB masquerading as MySQL you need to either use the mysql command on the command line or log into phpmyadmin to delete specific tables or all tables. I found it easier to start over every time rather than keep the settings.

Comment: I finally solved it. I was wrong about that the files didn't exist in the table file_managed. With the right query I found all those rows and deleted them. And now things runs smoothly again. I learn as I go :-).

Answer (score 0):

Also note that you can set file_replace to MigrateFile::FILE_EXISTS_REUSE - with this setting, if the file already exists in file_managed the migration will simply point to that existing file entity rather than attempt to create a new one. See the documentation at https://www.drupal.org/node/1540106.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. And thanks for all your work on 'migrate d2d'. Saved me an awful ot of time. I have already tried the "reuse" option, but I can't get it to work. All files in my image folder gets doubled anyway, with _0, _1 and so forth added to the end of the filename. I will give it another try though. When using "reuse" should the preserve_files option be set to 1 or not? Or maybe left out?

Comment: preserve_files shouldn't make a difference. FILE_EXISTS_REUSE actually reuses (or should reuse, anyway) at two levels - if the file_managed entry exists, reuse that; if not but the physical file exists, create a file_managed entry for it without recopying the file.

Could you post the specific field mappings you're using?